# Prepend fixed or variable length header in netty message

Tags: java, netty

I'm want to prepend a fixed or variable length header to all messages for a netty chat program.

#### Current State

I'm building a simple chat; all messages (currently) are *length* delimited using [`LengthFieldPrepender`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldPrepender.html) and [`LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html), 2 bytes for length part, and this works fine so far:

```
 +-------------+-------------------+  
 | <length>    | <message>         |  
 |    13       | 'Yo, waz up?'     | 
 +-------------+-------------------+
```

..and the pipeline

```
//inbound
pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder (1024,0,2,0,2));
pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
//outbound
pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(2));
pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

#### Goal

The goal is to add a header, either fixed or variable, containing the app name + version, to filter out invalid messages; this example uses the header `'nChat v1.0'`, 10 bytes fixed length:

```
 --------------+--------------+-------------------+  
 | <length>    | <header>     | <message>         |  
 |    23       | 'nChat v1.0' | 'Yo, waz up?'     | 
 --------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Adjusting the inbound pipeline to accommodate the header shouldn't be an issue, though I don't want the header stripped, so I left `initialBytesToStrip` at `2`:

```
pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder (1024,0,2,0,2));
pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

#### Problem

I'm not exactly sure what's the best approach for adding the header to the message. I'm assuming a custom handler is required; two ideas come to mind:

- Subclass `StringEncoder`, prepend the header to outgoing message, encode as usual.
- Create new handler, similar to `LengthFieldPrepender`, serialize header using `out.writeBytes("nChat v1.0".getBytes())`

I suspect the latter option is correct since the header, in principal, is no different than `LengthFieldPrepender` in terms of what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with; it supports variable length headers. I'm still a n00b at this, so comments welcome :-D

```
   public class HeaderFieldEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<ByteBuf> { 
      public HeaderFieldEncoder(String header){
         this.header = header;
      }     
      @Override
      protected void encode(
         ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
         ByteBuf msg,
         ByteBuf out
      )throws Exception {                           
         //header = "nChat v1.0"
         ByteBuf headerBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(
            header.getBytes(charset));                                    
         out.writeBytes(headerBuf);
         out.writeBytes(msg, msg.readerIndex(), msg.readableBytes());      
      }           
   }


   public class HeaderFieldDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<ByteBuf> {
      public HeaderFieldDecoder(String header){
         this.header = header;
      }
      @Override
      protected void decode(
         ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
         ByteBuf msg,
         List<Object> out
      )throws Exception {
         String extractedHeader = extractHeader(msg);
         //if desired, validate header
         //if(!header.equals(extractedHeader)
         String content = msg.toString(charset);
         out.add(content);         
      }

      private String extractHeader(ByteBuf msg){
         String headerField = null;
         if(msg.readableBytes() >= header.length()){
            byte[] headerBytes = new byte[header.length()];
            msg.readBytes(headerBytes, 0, header.length());
            headerField = new String(headerBytes, charset);
         }
         return headerField;
      }
   }
```

The working pipeline:

```
String header = "nChat v1.0";
//INBOUND 
pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1024,0,2,0,2));
pipeline.addLast(new HeaderFieldDecoder(header));
pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder());

//OUTBOUND
pipeline.addLast(new LengthFieldPrepender(2)); 
pipeline.addLast(new HeaderFieldEncoder(header));
pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder());
```

What do you think; is this valid? Am I cleaning up resources properly?

Comment: Looks OK to me. However, you could reduce the amount of object allocations.  For an instance, in `extractHeader(ByteBuf)`, you could use `ByteBuf.toString(offset, length, Charset)` to read the header field.